# Calling a JavaScript function inside a jQuery generated <a href...>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.notActiveId').change(function() {

        if ($(this).attr('value').length === 0 ) {

            $("#notActiveButton").html('');

        } else {

            $("#notActiveButton").html('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="setStatus(' + $(this).attr('value') + ', activate)" class="operationUnlock" >Activate</a>');

        }

    });
});
```

I'm calling with `$(this).attr('value')` a value from a select list named `notActiveId`. But the problem is how to write `$(this).attr('value')` in `setStatus()` function, because value of my select is in this form: `RZT_83848Rer` (so it consists of characters, underline and numbers).

If I try to write it as above, then I get a JavaScript error.

Comment: Can you show us some HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an old-school "onclick", why not add your element via jQuery?

```
$('#notActiveButton').empty().append($('<a/>', {
  href: '#', // the "javascript:" thing is basically bogus and unnecessary
  click: function () {
    setStatus(this.value, activate);
  },
  class: 'operationUnlock',
  text: 'Activate'
}));
```

Now, all this assumes that your "notActiveButton" element is some sort of legitimate container for your `<a>` tag. But anyway, doing it this way you get to write plain JavaScript without having to worry about the mess of quoting etc.